# How to merge two /etc/group files

Tags: text-processing, awk, files, group, merge

I have two  files in style of /etc/group :

```
root:x:0:
daemon:x:1:
bin:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:username
tty:x:5:
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:
mail:x:8:
news:x:9:
ubuntu:x:999:
```

And I want to merge them into a third file, but no GID should occur twice in the merged file. 
How could this be done using bash command? I was thinking that it could be done with `awk`, but I cannot find a solution at the moment.

EDIT 
I need to keep the original GID from each file
there could be two groups with same name, but not with same GID. in the output file the GID should be unique
`

Comment: Do you want to also merge the user lists if the same group appears in both files? Same by name or same by gid?

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, there can be two groups with same name, but not with same GID. in the output file the GID shoudl be unique

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN { OFS=":" } { print $1,"x",NR,$5 }' file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: I need to keep the original GID from file1 file2

Comment: If you have a collision, which one do you keep?

Comment: The first one should be kept

Answer (score 0):

This will select the first name and number from both files:

```
awk -F: -vOFS=":" '{if(!($1 in gname || $3 in gnumber)){print $1,"x",$3,$4};gname[$1]=1;gnumber[$3]=1}' file1 file2
```